# AVPlayerItem isPlaybackBufferFull always false

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, key-value-observing, avkit

Trying to learn AVFoundation by debugging and understanding all properties of `AVPlayerItem`.

I've noticed something when I run a video playing on simulator (or device), that `AVPlayerItem`'s property `isPlaybackBufferFull` is always `false`.
On the player view, I am printing all the properties and updating them thanks to KVO. 
[image: debugview] 
On the debug view, the loaded time ranges gets updated correctly. When it's fully loaded, the property `isPlaybackBufferFull` doesn't get set to `true`.

```
let newItem: AVPlayerItem = .init(url: url)
player.replaceCurrentItem(with: newItem)
self.isPlaybackBufferFullObserver = item.observe(\.isPlaybackBufferFull, changeHandler: self.onIsPlaybackBufferFullObserverChanged)

private func onIsPlaybackBufferFullObserverChanged(playerItem: AVPlayerItem, change: NSKeyValueObservedChange<Bool>) {
    if playerItem.isPlaybackBufferFull {
      // Breakpoint should normally stops here            
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything? Shouldn't `isPlaybackBufferFull` be true at some point?

Comment: did you find a reason why isPlaybackBufferFull always false? I am also having issues with canPlayFastForward always returning false.

Comment: @STerrier , I am not sure why under the hood it doesn't turn the boolean to `true`. But something interesting to note... if you set `newItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration = 1.0`, the `isPlaybackBufferFull` will become `true` .

Comment: yeah it's a bit odd but thanks for the info!